# python 3 hex conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert some code from 2 to 3.  I have

```
val = str(''.join(map(chr, list(range(0, 256, 8)))))
```

and I need to translate

```
x = str(val).encode('hex')
```

and

```
x.decode('hex')
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what is your problem? I don't see a question here.

Comment: Probably he got `LookupError: unknown encoding: hex`

Answer (score 1):

In python2, your code produces:

```
In [4]: val = str(''.join(map(chr, list(range(0, 256, 8))))) ;  val
Out[4]: '\x00\x08\x10\x18 (08@HPX`hpx\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xd0\xd8\xe0\xe8\xf0\xf8'
In [5]: x = str(val).encode('hex') ; x
Out[5]: '0008101820283038404850586068707880889098a0a8b0b8c0c8d0d8e0e8f0f8'
In [6]: x.decode('hex')
Out[6]: '\x00\x08\x10\x18 (08@HPX`hpx\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xd0\xd8\xe0\xe8\xf0\xf8'
```

To get the similar output in python3:

```
In [19]: import codecs
In [20]: val = ''.join(map(chr, range(0, 256, 8))) ; val
Out[20]: '\x00\x08\x10\x18 (08@HPX`hpx\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0¨°¸ÀÈÐØàèðø'
In [21]: x = codecs.encode(val.encode('latin-1'), 'hex_codec') ; x
Out[21]: b'0008101820283038404850586068707880889098a0a8b0b8c0c8d0d8e0e8f0f8'
In [22]: codecs.decode(x, 'hex_codec')
Out[22]: b'\x00\x08\x10\x18 (08@HPX`hpx\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xd0\xd8\xe0\xe8\xf0\xf8'
```

Notes:

1. The python3 version of `x` above is a byte-string.  Since it is entirely ASCII, it can be converted to unicode simply via `x.decode()`.
2. The display of `val` toward the end of the string in the python3 code above does not match the python2 version.  For a method of creating `val` which does match, see the next section.

#### Alternatives

Use `bytes` to create the string.  Use `binascii.hexlify` to convert it to hex:

```
In [15]: val = bytes(range(0, 256, 8))
In [16]: val
Out[16]: b'\x00\x08\x10\x18 (08@HPX`hpx\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xd0\xd8\xe0\xe8\xf0\xf8'
In [17]: binascii.hexlify(val)
Out[17]: b'0008101820283038404850586068707880889098a0a8b0b8c0c8d0d8e0e8f0f8'
```

#### More on unicode and character 0xf8

You wanted ø to be 0xf8.  Here is how to make that work:

```
>>> s = chr( int('f8', 16) )
>>> s
'ø'
```

And, to convert `s` back to a hex number:

```
>>> hex(ord(s))
'0xf8'
```

Note that 0xf8' is the unicode code point of 'ø' and that that is not the same as the byte string representing the unicode character 'ø' which is:

```
>>> s.encode('utf8')
b'\xc3\xb8'
```

So, 'ø' is the 248th (0xf8) character in the unicode set and its byte-string representation is b'\xc3\xb8'.

Comment: I'm stuck with strings.  Can't create them with bytes.  Any idea how to translate the string to bytes?  I need ø to be b'\xf8', which doesn't happen with utf-8 (and ascii throws and error, obviously).

Comment: @Kevin Let me know if what I have added to the answer helps.

Comment: In 2.7, binascii.hexlify(bytes(chr(248))) = 'f8', which is good.  In 3.3, binascii.hexlify(bytes(chr(248),'utf-8')) = b'c3b8', which isn't.

Comment: @Kevin If you are looking for the UTF-8 ordinal value, don't use `hexlify`, use `hex(ord(s))`.  On the other hand, I just noticed that `binascii.hexlify(bytes(chr(248),'latin1')) == b'f8'`.  Are your python2 strings in the Latin1 codec?

Comment: @eryksun I have revised the answer to include your suggested code.

Comment: @Kevin Assuming your python2 code was based in Latin1, I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python 2 code:

```
val = str(''.join(map(chr, list(range(0, 256, 8)))))
x = str(val).encode('hex')
x.decode('hex')
```

Let's make version that works on both Python 2 and 3:

```
import binascii

val = bytearray(range(0, 0x100, 8))
x = binascii.hexlify(val)
binascii.unhexlify(x)
```